# My code runs into Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am following [tutorial](http://docs.huihoo.com/hibernate/annotations-reference-3.2.1/ch01.html) to implement hibernate on my project, although I have set the dialect in my configuration file but it runs into following error.

my hibernate.cfg.xml is in Web-inf > classes

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>
        <property name="connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Project1
        </property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">
            org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
        </property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

                <mapping class="com.project.class1" />
                <mapping class="com.project.class2" />

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**HbernateUtil.java**

```
package com.project.util;

import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;

public class HibernateUtil {


    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {

            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log exception!
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static Session getSession(){
        try{
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
        }catch(HibernateException h){
            h.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ognl</groupId>
            <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0-Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
                    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opensymphony</groupId>
            <artifactId>xwork-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.GA</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jline</artifactId>
                <groupId>jline</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.ga</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Prepend `hibernate.` in all the property names.

```
<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
        com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Project1
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
        org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
    </property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

            <mapping class="com.project.class1" />
            <mapping class="com.project.class2" />

</session-factory>
```

**EDIT**

Check whether you have `hibernate.cfg.xml` file in your classpath. And do the following code change. Must call `configure()` before calling `buildSessionFactory()`.

```
static {
    try {

        sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Log exception!
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the file you have editted is being used? If this is in a Web application then did you redeploy?

Comment: It runs into following error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure()Lorg/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration;

Comment: Uncomment your hibernate dependencies in pom.xml